# Question bans specific information about it?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I was wondering how to get out of a question ban (might I ever get one again) The help page just provides this:

> How can I get out of a question ban?
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions
>   which were poorly received.

Not very clear. I have had a question ban on Stack Overflow before but I just edited my questions, got like 2 vote ups and I got to ask again. I have read you can also get out of a question ban by providing good answers. The time I've spent with a question ban, I've also provided some answers which got voted up/accepted, but every time I checked I didn't lose the question ban but editing questions did work for me.

**What ways can get you out of a question ban exactly?**

I am currently not in a question ban. I am just wondering about all the things that would work.

Comment: Have you undeleted and improved your deleted questions?

Comment: @hims056 please read the whole question. I am currently not in a question ban.

Comment: It's not clear on purpose. Everything one can and needs to know is already in the linked post.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Okay somehow you helped me with the possible duplicate. So it MIGHT help providing good answers... Nobody knows?

Comment: @loko: Well *some* people do know, but they're not going to actually provide the full information as knowing the exact criteria involved in a ban just enables people to cheat the system. Question bans are in place when contributions are so low in quality that they are detrimental to the site in general. If you don't want another question ban then don't ask low-quality unresearched questions and you'll be fine. *That's* the magic formula - ask good stuff, and give good answers.

Comment: @loko only the devs know the exact formula, but it's kept a top secret. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah thanks thats what I wanted to know!